# Broken Image Icon When Using Echo In PHP

Tags: php, echo

I am trying to query the image file names from the database using the Id inputted by the user and want to display the images with the resulting file names form the select statement. However the echo function is showing only the broken image icons instead of the image itself. How can I fix this? Thanks!

```
//$searchValue is the Id inputted by the user in the html page 
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT FileName FROM images WHERE Id='$searchValue'");

//$folder is the path where the images are currently stored
$folder = "C:/xampp/htdocs/images/";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $file = $row["FileName"];
    echo '<img src="'.$folder.$file.'"><br />';
}
```

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: you won't be able to return a full file system path to a client.

Comment: Is generated path (in dev tools inspection) correct ? Have you a not found reqest in network tab ? The problem in absolutely in the path. Maybe you made a mistake somewhere, double check everything !

Comment: There is Quite a bit wrong with this. You're exposing your Root directories and have a massive SQL injection vulnerability. I'd suggest you go back and read the MYSQLI documentation for a start. And then look at how you go about managing web facing directories.

Comment: What’s an alternate way to do it? How should I be hiding the folder path? Just use the root directory so I don’t expose the entire folder location?

Comment: The src value needs to be a URL, not a disk path.

Comment: If your project is stored in `htdocs` folder `<img src="images/image.jpg">` should be enough to display it.